# Getting proper data model when rendering into outlet in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to create a select box in a modal that has a list of all cars in inventory. If I enter the app from a page that has all the data loaded and open the modal it works correctly. However if I am on a route that doesn't have the data loaded, then open the modal the select options do not show. Furthermore the options will never update from that point. How do I get the proper data to load? Should not this work since I am fetching the data direct from the store?

```
Dms.SellDialogController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  cars: function() {
    return this.store.find('car').filterProperty('isSold', false);
  }.property('model'),
  selectedCar: '',
  carObjects: function() {
    var cars = this.get('cars').map(function(car) {
      return obj = {id: car.get('id'), key: car.get('keyNumber'), label: 'KEY#:'+car.get('keyNumber') + ' - STOCK#:' + car.get('stock')+' '+car.get('year')+' '+car.get('vModel')};
    });
    cars.sort(function(a, b){return a.key-b.key;})
    return cars;
  }.property('route'),
  title: 'Select the car you are selling'
});
```

ApplicationRoute...
...

```
openModal: function(modalName, model) {
  this.render(modalName, {
    into: 'application',
    outlet: 'modal',
    model: model
  });
},
```

Action to open modal inside application template

```
{{action 'openModal' 'sellDialog' model}}
```

and the templates

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/modal-dialog">
  <div class='modal-overlay' {{action "closeModal" target=cntrllr}}>
    <div class='modal' {{action "dngn" target=cntrllr bubbles=false}}>
      <div class='modal-content'>
        <div class='modal-header'>
          <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" {{action "closeModal" target=cntrllr}}><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h4>
        </div>
        {{yield}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="sellDialog">
  {{#modal-dialog title=title cntrllr=controller model=model}}
    <div class="modal-body">
      <span class='pull-left'>Key Number: 
        {{view "select" content=carObjects optionValuePath="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.label" selection=selectedCar}}
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
       <button {{action "modalAction" controller "sell" selectedCar.id}}>Sell</button>
       <button {{action "closeModal"}}>Cancel</button>
    </div>
  {{/modal-dialog}}
</script>
```

UPDATE 2015/5/4:
I have a hack to make it work for now. I added a cars property in the application route and I am getting it in SellDialogController. This looks like a bug to me. I will make a jsFiddle when I get some time and check it further before issuing a bug report.

Comment: You may want to consider using the `{[render}}` helper here, instead of an outlet.

Comment: Would that cause the modal to always be rendered? It needs only to be rendered when called. Further issues with reusability will make render a bad choice here.

Answer (score 1):

try using setupController on the Application Route, since setupController is always called.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: Ember.RSVP.hash({
    optionsForSelect: function() {
     // fetch your select data here
    },
    otherData: function() {
     // get your regular model data here
    }
  }),
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this.controllerFor('sellDialog').set('model', model.optionsForSelect);
     this.controller.set('model', model.otherData);
  }
});
```

Comment: No it didn't I am using a work around currently. I will post an update soon.